# How can I represent an instance as a typed value

Tags: python, oop

I have two classes a `Container` and a `Field` class.  I want to represent the `Field` class as the value it contains.  It needs to be typed so I can do some meaningful operations with it.

```
import datetime

class Field(object):
    date = datetime.date.today()

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.date

class Container(object):
    value = Field().date
    value_2 = Field()

c = Container()
print c.value.isoformat() # perfect
print c.value_2.isoformat() # boo fails
```

I know SQLAlchemy does something along these lines.  You define attributes as column instances which return a typed value to you.

Comment: Make `__repr__()` return `str(self.date)`.  It needs to return a string, or else there will be an error.  If you really want to go through `__repr__()`, you will need to use `eval()` or `ast.literal_eval()`.

Comment: @zondo I don't know the best method to do this.  `__repr__` was just my initial thought.  Is there a better way?

Comment: I mean that it's just not a good idea to go from instance to string to instance.  You should just use the `date` attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is perfect use case for a [descriptor.](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html) Basically define [`__get__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__get__) method on `Field` class and return the expected value from it. You can also define [`__set__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__set__) as per your requirements, for example not allowing them to set values of other types.

```
import datetime


class Field(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = datetime.date.today()

    def __get__(self, instance=None, type=None):
        if instance is not None:
            return self.val
        return self


class Container(object):
    value_1 = Field()
    value_2 = Field()

c = Container()
print c.value_1.isoformat() # 2016-03-03
print c.value_2.isoformat() # 2016-03-03
```

Comment: I haven't thought about implementing this before. Thanks for this!